# SharePoint and Excel Online Data Connections

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, excel-online

I'm experimenting here so please bear with me or offer some direction/starter for ten.

We have SharePoint, Excel Online.  I had an XLS on my desktop with a data connection out to CSV file to load a table, nothing to special but works a dream when the CSV was updated and the refresh done.

If I want to do something like this on SharePoint, so if I use XLS online a can not see anywhere under Data to create the Data Connection, what's missing?

Ideally I want the XLS online to be able to connect to a CSV elsewhere (on SharePoint or our Network) - what do I need to look into to make this work?

Comment: Sorry but  just to clarify, you want to load an Excel workbook from a CSV file and all of this sits on SharePoint, is that right?

Comment: It can do yes or somewhere else on our network,  Let's say for arguments sake that will be SharePoint.  However with Excel online I can not add a data connection.

Comment: You don’t need to, that’s what PowerAutomate/LogicApps is for. Connecting to on prem networks takes a lot more effort so put your CSV on SharePoint and then use LA/PA to get the data and load it to the workbook using built in actions or office scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the starter for ten on that, I've never used them so will take a look.

Comment: No worries man, good luck.  We're all here to help if you get really stuck.